# Get the first and last times for each day with Python datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of timestamps in this format: '2016-08-01 13:02:57' or "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f"

I would like to get the first and last time for each day. So for if there were two days 8/1 and 7/29 the function would return 4 values. For example:

```
8/1
first: '2016-08-01 13:02:57'
last: '2016-08-01 13:08:44'

7/29
first: '2016-07-29 14:34:02'
last: '2016-07-29 14:37:35'
```

The first time is the one that occurs first in that day, the last time is the one that occurs last in that day.

Comment: What is the *last time*?

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my question to be more clear.

Comment: Is there timezone data? Are they all in the same timezone?

Comment: All in the same timezone.

Comment: So basically you want the max and min,`mn, mx = min(list_of_datetime),max(list_of_datetime)`?

Comment: Yes, but for each day.

Comment: All are mixed in one list? Generally If you add a sample of input with expected output it makes life simpler.

Comment: Yes, they're all in one list.

Comment: The list is unordered I presume?

Comment: The list is not ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by year-month-day then get the min and max:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
dates = ['2016-08-01 13:02:54',............]
for dte in dates:
    key, _ = dte.split()
    d[key].append(dte)

for k,v in d.items():
    print(min(v), max(v))
```

Because of the date formats you don't need to convert to datetimes, lexicographical comparison  will work fine. You could make a function that does the min and max in one loop but it may not be as fast as the builtins.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I used key = dte.month to take advantage of the datetime format.

Comment: @sparrow, no worries, I did not realize they were actual datetimes, it would be safe to compare just as string but if they are already datetimes then sure but  the years and days could be different though no? You would want `(dte.year, dte.month,dte.day)` no?

Comment: That's a good point. I think strings is better too because it will be less expensive for me to convert the data upstream.

Comment: Yes, not having to convert to datetimes will be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A lexical compare is with your datetime format gives min and max dates. So you simply have to group all datetimes with the same date in one list each:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dates = ['2016-08-01 13:02:57', '2016-08-01 13:08:44', ...]
dates_and_times = defaultdict(list)
for date in dates:
    d, t = date.split()
    dates_and_times[d].append(t)

for date, times in dates_and_times.items():
    print(date, min(times))
    print(date, max(times))
```

Answer (score -1):

To sensibly group your data I would probably use a dictionary in the following fashion by first splitting your string into the date half and time half.

```
d = dict()
for item in L:
    if item in d:
        d[item] = [time]
    else:
        d[item].append(time)
```

Then you have dict mapping certain dates to a list of times. Then it's probably trivial to employ some datetime function which can do max(list) and min(list) to give you earliest and latest times.